# findViewById(R.id.something) in a non-activity class

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, user-interface

In my activity I go through a bunch of controls(input fields), and create a

```
for(ControlTemplate field: fieldMap.get(string))
{
    View view = field.getFieldControl(true, this);
    l.addView(view, new PredicateLayout.LayoutParams(2, 0));
}
```

The ControlTemplate's getFieldControl contains a switch statement that should return different types of views.

```
  case LABEL:                       
        view = new TextView(context);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((TextView) view).setText(value);
  break;
```

However, I'd like to be able to create the views from xml definitions, but this is not possible since the class is no activity, and therefore it has no layout. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
case TEXTBOX:   
    view = (EditText) passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
break;
```

where passedActivity is the activity that created the ControlField class. Is there a way to pass the current activity as an argument, or perhaps only its layout assets?

Comment: pass the context to the non activity class constructor and use the same to find the id.

Comment: @Raghunandan what's the difference?

Comment: I have passed the context, but how do I get the id from the context?

Comment: If you have a context then you can inflate the view and you can use findviewById on that view to get its child views.

Comment: I believe you can import R if you're in a different class.

Comment: I always get suspicious of the design when non-activity classes are touching UI.  Far better to pass values between classes and to signal update events using `Interface`.  IMHO, good Android design is predicated on activities owning the UI.  You also run the risk of some painful and subtle memory leaks passing activity contexts around your application.  You must guarantee that anything receiving an activity context has a life time no greater than that of the activity context and no static references.  It's dangerous from on OOP perspective since a receiving class has no such constraint.

Comment: I agree with Pragnani. you can pass the context inflate the layout and then find the id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) for loading layout assets

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_message, parent, false);
```

For parameters of inflate see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

```
public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

**Parameters**

```
resource
```

ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.layout.main_page)

```
 root
```

Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

```
attachToRoot
```

Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

Comment: That seems like it might work! What should I pass as the parent paramenter?

Comment: pass the activity context to the constructor  of the non activity class new NonActivityClass(ActivityName.this); then use the same to inflate the layout and find the id of the required view.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the context from your activity to your other class, you can go through the context for everything you need. You should be able to get R from the context, as well as the associated views.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your problem correctly, you need to pass the context of your activity to the ControlTemplate class.

For example
I send **this**(current context).

```
adapter = new ChecklistBaseAdapter(this, checklistitems);
```

when calling my base adapter class

```
public ChecklistBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Checklist> results)
```

i can then reference to change controls on current activity with my ChecklistBaseAdapter class.

Hope it helps